# How can I get the "exclude" product images in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I want to display the "exclude" product images in a section on my product page.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
$excludedImages = new Varien_Data_Collection();
$images = $product->getMediaGallery('images');
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    if ($image['disabled'])
    {
        $image['url'] = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
        $image['id'] = isset($image['value_id']) ? $image['value_id'] : null;
        $image['path'] = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']);
        $excludedImages->addItem(new Varien_Object($image));
    }
}
```

Now the `$excludedImages` collection contain every excluded images.

Comment: Thanx man, it helped me.. :-)